# Change the const of an element of a struct

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I have a pointer to a:

```
struct KeyValue {
  K key;
  V value;
}
```

and I want to return a reference to the same memory location interpreted as a

```
struct IKeyValue {
  const K key;
  V value;
}
```

Is there a clean way to do it in C++11?

The reference to IKeyValue should be valid as long as any reference to the original KeyValue is valid.

The reason I am doing this is because I am implementing a `HashTable<K, V>` using open addressing. As a consequence I have an array of `KeyValue` with some of them being fully constructed (key and value constructed) and some of them half constructed (only key constructed to `empty_key` or `tombstone_key`). I want the iterators to this structure be used such that `it->key` can be read but not modified and `it->value` can be read and modified. And I prefer not to have something such as `it->key()` and `it->value()` as it is done in the standard library.

As it seems difficult to do this, I am thinking of another option as suggested by the answers. I can construct an array of IKeyValue inside my HashTable with:

```
IKeyValue* p = (IKeyValue*)malloc(n * sizeof(IKeyValue));
```

But then, am I allowed to use emplacement new in order to construct just a key or a value with placement new?

Comment: How would you manage scope/lifetime for the objects?

Comment: If this is a sort of pair you use to in a map, making key non-const to begin with is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 4):

You can provide reference members and a constructor

```
struct IKeyValue {
     const K& key;
     V& value;
     IKeyValue(KeyValue& x) : key(x.key), value(x.value) {}
};
```

But as mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362289/change-the-const-of-an-element-of-a-struct/41362355#comment69925808_41362289), the lifetime management for the referenced instances could become a problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to pay the price of copying elements. And I want to be able to change the value at its original location through the IKeyValue referrence.

Comment: @InsideLoop Fixed that.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, but it would be better if no pointer/reference is created.

Comment: @InsideLoop _"if no pointer/reference is created"_ Well, you have to choose either the one or the other way. There's no 3rd one viable.

Comment: There must be a way as the standard library allows to get iterators that behave this way for syd::unordered_map

Comment: @InsideLoop Take a look at the reference of [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). `value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`. It already stores the keys as `const`, it doesn't offer a view unto them.

Answer (score 4):

In `IKeyValue`, use accessor functions rather than data fields:

```
struct IKeyValue {
private:
    KeyValue & keyValue;
public:
    IKeyValue (KeyValue & keyValue) : keyValue (keyValue) {}

    K const & key () const { return keyValue.key; }
    V & value () { return keyValue.value; }
    V const & value () const { return keyValue.value; }
};

KeyValue kv = ...;
IKeyValue ikv (kv);

... ikv.key (); // returns kv.key;
ikv.value () = ...; // sets kv.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't , as they are not the same type, nor `IKeyValue` is a derived class of `KeyValue`.

You need to redesign your code to use something different, like returning a view of the class instead.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is to make your data members private, and provide getters and setters when needed. From what you wrote, it seems that you want the key to be read-only, and the value to be read-write.  So you can do this:

```
class KeyValue
{
public:
   KeyValue(K k, V v) : key(k), value(v) {}
   K get_key() const {return key;}
   V get_value() const {return value;}
   void set_value(V v) {value = v;}
private:
   K key;
   V value;
};
```

Now the key can only be set in the constructor, and is read-only from that moment on.

Comment: Getters and setter en-masse are hardly clean. And it doesn't solve the problem. You still can't prevent the user from modifying `key` if the returned reference is non-`const`, nor can you allow them to modify `value` if the reference is `const`.

Comment: I love the answer, but it does not exactly answer the question.

Comment: This is hardly "en-masse". I am specifying a policy of which data members are read-only, and which are read-write. And I am not returning references at all. I am returning values.

Comment: This does not allow `KeyValue::key` to be changed after creation, which is a requirement

Comment: Then you misunderstood the question, because you did not answer it. And you went full-blown java by complicating a simple aggregate.

Comment: @M.M I don't see that requirement anywhere in the question. It looks to me like the author is trying to do a simple thing in a complicated way.

Comment: @StoryTeller I highly recommend that you take a look at "Effective C++", 2nd edition, by Scott Meyers.

Comment: It seems to me that `KeyValue` is used in various places in the code, and OP wants to create a view onto it in some other places that only allows modification of the value.   OP didn't say that there are any restrictions on `KeyValue` so an answer should not place restrictions.

Comment: I've read it thank you, the third edition even. Scott Meyers' advice is generally good, but not perfect. Sending me to read a book hardly proves a point. Member functions that just give access to member are a failure to encapsulate. You don't impose any policy here that is above direct access.

Comment: @M.M Now we are making assumptions about how KeyValue is used in the rest of the code. And since we don't know that, we should fall back on the basic C++ design principles, such as making all data members private and providing accessors if and when needed.

Comment: @StoryTeller but you do impose a policy.`key` is now read-only, and `value` is read-write. If accessors are a failure to encapsulate, then what do you call public data members?

Comment: Allow me to re-iterate. The OP wants to modify `key`, otherwise they wouldn't have defined it as non-`const` (and having a "read-only" member as non-`const` is a code smell btw). As for `value`, the accessors add nothing. They are just code bloat.

Comment: The knee-jerk reaction of "private" everything, even in a simple aggregate is not a well-thought out design. I'm sorry. An aggregate is not meant to encapsulate anything. It has no behavior other than simply clumping data together, and direct access is the simplest cleanest approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is quite a weird solution I'm offering here, and some would argue an abusive one, but if your "Value" is always modifiable, you could do something like:

```
struct KeyValue {
  K key;
  mutable V value;
};
```

and then hold a `const KeyValue&` where you want to lock in the constness of the key.